# open pdf in to another pdfviewer application from my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgpdf, cgpdfcontext

I have one pdf in my application and I want to open that pdf but not in my applicaton.
When ever i'll click or open that pdf it will ask me to open that pdf in another application of pdf viewer availbale on my device i wnt to know that is it possible & if possible how can i do that?

-Thanx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Local PDF in Safari in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707337/open-local-pdf-in-safari-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use only apple PDF viewer afaik. I dont know if I am wrong here. (Please  correct me in this case)

**To open PDF in iBook app, use this code**

```
NSString *stringURL = @"itms-books:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
NSString *stringURL = @"itms-bookss:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: This opens ebooks in iBooks not PDFs in Safari.

Comment: @Abizern He is asking for PDFViewer.. Dont u think iBooks is a PDFViewer.. not Safari??? Please READ PROPERLY BEFORE DOWN-VOTING.. I HAVE WROTE THERE THIS OPENS IN iBook app..!!!

Comment: thanx a lot to every one i have got the solution with help of UIDocumentation interaction as below:                   
 http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks

Comment: If you've found a different solution, why did you accept this as the correct answer?

Comment: @Abizern  this also true if we have implemented documentationintreraction in our app