# Can't open .PDF or .DOC(X) in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, iframe

I'm developing an iPhone app using PhoneGap, Xcode, HTML and JavaScript. I have an iFrame that should view documents (right now I am using a test document instead of allowing the user to choose - that's coming later) that have been downloaded (again, i chose the document). I tried using a .pdf file and a .docx file which are both supported by iPhone, but clicking the button I coded opens them in Safari instead of the iFrame. Here's the code to view the document (JavaScript and HTML);

```
    function viewOnline() {
        var site = "file://" + pathToRoot + "/editme.txt"
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', site);
    }

    <button onclick="viewOnline();">View Online</button></li>

    <iframe id="myIframe" style="width: 210; height: 210px;" seamless="seamless" src=""></iframe>
```

Is it just not possible to view .pdf etc files in iFrame or is there something wrong with my code?

** `pathToRoot` is coded (and tested to be correct) elsewhere in the application - so i don't need to hard-code the file path, which will change when i transfer it to the device instead of the simulator.

** if you need the code where i download the file, then i can give you it - just comment below

** I'm also fairly new to working with Xcode and PhoneGap so if i need to alter something with them if you could give as much detail as possible that would be great - Thanks so much in advance

**Edit**

I know about the OpenWhitelistURLsInWebView, and have enabled it and allowed the website i'm downloading from in the ExternalHosts array - but it still won't work.

Comment: [mobilesafari won't display pdf according to this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8548880/1986499)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Most of the mobile browsers doesn't come preloaded with Adobe plugins and all. It's not a desktop you see. Its a mobile. So it's not possible unless you create a own browser and include the adobe plugin(meaning you have to write pdf rendition logic because the plugin wont work in mobile).

Comment: iPhones render pdf documents just fine. Since cordova is essentially a webview within an xcode project, i see no reason why this should not work?

Comment: @MartinSommervold: Sorry was thinking in aspect of droid. And moreover i haven't really tried anything with file protocol in iPhone

Answer (score 1):

iFrames are very rarely needed and are often employed for wrong reasons. Often you can achieve the exact same thing you are going for using normal styles and simpler markup.

Also, googling phonegap/cordova iframe gives many results that spell out trouble with iFrames. For the official implications guide on them see [iFrame Usage](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/iFrame-Usage).

In your case these are the things you need to consider:

> Enabling iFrames on PhoneGap-iOS requires that you whitelist the
>   iframe domains and enable "OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView". While this
>   doesn't sound like a problem, many applications want to open specific
>   sites in MobileSafari (not a ChildBrowser), which cannot be
>   accomplished easily when "OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" is enabled.
>
> To change OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView open the Cordova.plist file in
>   Xcode.
>
> To whitelist a domain. Add it to the ExternalHosts array in the
>   Cordova.plist file. Simply press the + next to the ExternalHosts title
>   and when the item0 appears bellow add your domain to the value section
>   (in the format example.com).

Comment: i've seen that OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView thing but i have enabled it and put in the website that i'm downloading from but it still won't work - that's why I'm asking. sorry i should have put that in. i'll edit it now